# How can I print a string of ascii codes Iet's say 15 random ones in a list?

Tags: python, random, passwords, ascii

I'm a newbie to python, I'm trying to print out a list of 15-20 random ascii codes as part of a random password generator, could anyone please help?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import string
>>> import random
>>> alphabet = string.printable.split()[0]
>>> password = "".join([random.choice(alphabet) for i in range(15)])
>>> print password
dg!>]aGF(&T9,Q'
```

This choice of `alphabet` takes all printable ASCII characters except all kinds of whitespace by splitting the string `string.printable` at the first whitespace. It works due to the sorting of `string.printable` which is

```
>>> string.printable
'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'
```